# how to search for a term only in non test files

Tags: shell, command-line

I use ack and I like it.

However from time to time I need to search for something in my code base and I want to ignore all the files residing in test directory. Basically all the files which have *test* in their absolute path should be not included in the search.

How do I achieve that?

I am willing to have a custom bash script. Something like

ack_no_test "application" -> search for "application" in all files but ignore files residing in test directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man ack`:

> --[no]ignore-dir=DIRNAME
>              Ignore directory (as CVS, .svn, etc are ignored). May be used
>              multiple times to ignore multiple directories. For example, mason
>              users may wish to include --ignore-dir=data. The --noignore-dir
>              option allows users to search directories which would normally be
>              ignored (perhaps to research the contents of .svn/props
>              directories).

Comment: this is beyond embarrasing. I looked at ack help but looks like I missed this one. thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

one could add "test" to the "repodirs" var in [findrepo](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/findrepo).

Personally I think ack to too complicated/slow and "non unixy",
as it doesn't reuse the existing unix toolkit.